# Is toilet paper to blame for water from washing machine flooding in basement?

Tags: toilet, washing-machine, sewage

I moved in this old house two months ago. In the basement, some water
ousted by the washer  flooded out on the basement floor when someone used the washer yesterday.

He said the sewage system was blocked and blamed me on flushing toilet paper together with stool into the toilet located on the second floor.

I was wondering if there's any valid reason behind the blame, and any connection between the toilet and the washer in the sewage system.

Thanks.

Comment: Being an old house, it's quite possible that the waste pipes are either substandard or degraded over time.  So the idea that overloading them with too much material at one time caused a clog may be reasonable.  You can either live with it and be careful or hire someone to update the plumbing so that it's no longer an issue.

Comment: One potential problem is that the drain pipes could be so old that they are very narrow -- if the house was built before modern plumbing codes.  Or the local plumbing code could be that old, even if the house isn't.   I've seen this in Texas, Mexico, and Norway.

Comment: Who is "He" and what authority do they have to be placing blame? Toilets are supposed to handle solids and toilet paper no problem. If your plumbing system cannot handle it and "He" knew about it then "He" is the a$$hole. Worse yet, it also means that your plumbing system has a serious issue that "He" is neglecting.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to make it more clear who the participants are.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus A tenant. The house is old, but I am not sure how the toilet paper could cause water from the washing machine to flood in the basement. Isn't toilet paper water soluble?

Comment: "He" is a loon. Solids + toilet paper is not an unusual expectation unless you used a whole roll for a single flush. They can blame you all they want and you can tell them to go pound sand. The landlord needs to properly fix the issue so that your plumbing isn't so fragile.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't mention if the house is on a septic system or city sewer. Septic systems need period inspection and maintenance, like occasionally pumping the tank.  One source of clogs not mentioned in the other answer is roots growing into the building sewer.  Also, in old houses, 'Orangeburg' pipes were sometimes used for the sewer connection; these can collapse over time and cause problems.

Without a thorough inspection it's hard to say what the problem is, but it's safe to say that the problem is not flushing toilet paper.  This situation does need to be addressed, because it likely will get worse in time

Also, now wondering what "He" does with his toilet paper

Comment: Oops. Forgot roots. I've had those too - and all the others...

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR You most likely have a slow main drain and toilet paper + washing machine managed to tip it over the edge.

Clogs can happen for a *lot* of reasons, including:

- Grease - try not to put large quantities down the kitchen sink
- Hair - Use hair catchers on tub and shower drains
- Toilet paper
- Lint from washing machine - Put a [lint catcher](https://amzn.to/3TQ8PeG) (example on Amazon in case you've never seen these)
- Objects that should *never* go in the drain (small children are excellent at finding these...)
- Broken Pipes
- Roots - There are chemicals that, in theory, can help, but once they are a problem they exacerbate all the other problems because stuff sticks together on the roots.

With the exception of broken pipes and large solid objects (toys, etc.), I believe most clogs are due to an accumulation of grease, hair, lint and other "little stuff". Once the pipe narrows enough, toilet paper and other things that normally would go through just fine are unable to get through and you now have a true clog instead of just a slow drain.

If toilet paper was what caused the latest problem then most likely you already had a slow drain and the combination of a sudden large batch of toilet paper making its way slowly through the drain combined with a *huge* amount of water from the washing machine resulted in the overflow.

So toilet paper isn't the real cause (usually) of a clog. And the washing machine is pretty much the acid test of "do you have a clog". Most things (dishwasher, toilet, etc.) that push out a lot of water at one time only use a few gallons. Most other things (sink, shower) are relatively slow - e.g., 1 - 2 gallons per minute. But a top load washing machine can fill with as much as 20 gallons of water and then push that water out *very* quickly, which can overload a slow drain - trust me, I know from experience.

In my experience, toilets actually clog *first* when you truly have too much toilet paper (and other things...). They are actually designed that way, and once you do a little plunging to get everything out of the toilet, the drain pipes can usually handle it all without a problem. There might be an exception with really old pipes, but that would be unusual *unless there is already a partially clogged pipe (a.k.a., slow drain).

What to do next? The usual answers are chemicals (which are pretty nasty, but they often work very well), snake (a lot of work) or possibly pushing a lot of air through (a few ways to do that - I find it works well for a 100% or nearly 100% clog but not for a slow drain).

In a rental it is probably not a good idea to use chemicals without the landlord's permission. While nearly all the chemicals, no matter how nasty, say they are safe for all pipes, the landlord could still try to blame you for problems if you use chemicals. Same for snaking beyond a feet.

Comment: OP stated the house is old so it could have metal plumbing. I would add a strong disclaimer about chemicals that sit in metal plumbing and how they can deteriorate the integrity of said plumbing.

Answer (score 1):

Proper toilet paper is designed to disintegrate rapidly into small bits when soaked in water and agitated.  It should not be able to block pipes.

Wet wipes should never be flushed.  They don't break down in water and will easily block sewer pipes, especially when combined with grease from a kitchen.